# Python While Loop Syntax

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
class Solution: 
    def display(self,head):
        current = head
        while current:
            print(current.data,end=' ')
            current = current.next
```

Hello, I am having some difficulties understanding the above while loop, AFAIK you need to have a condition with a while loop, so:

```
while (stuff) == True:
```

But the above code has:

```
while current:
```

Is this the same as:

```
while current == head:
```

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be confused about the meaning of the statement above the while loop. It has nothing to do with the loop or it's conditional. Instead, it is copying the variable `head` to the variable `current`. Current is then converted to a boolean and checked for it's 'truthiness' as [Mariusz Jamro](http://stackoverflow.com/users/342473/mariusz-jamro)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38230275/2465194) below explains.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `while current:` syntax literally means `while bool(current) == True:`. The value will be converted to bool first and than compared to `True`. In python everyting converted to bool is `True` unless it's `None`, `False`, zero or an empty collection.

See the [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) section for reference.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

Your loop can be considered as

```
while current is not None:
```

because the parser will try to interpret current as a boolean (and None, empty list/tuple/dict/string and 0 evaluate to False)

Comment: No, it is more like `while current is not None and current is not False and current is not [] and current is not {} and current is not 0 and current is not "":`. Actually, it's `while bool(current) == True:`

Comment: There are other falsy values in Python than `None` so this is incorrect.

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more complete... but current.next is most likely to return None if there is no next element.
Moreover, `while bool(current)` is enough, no need to check for equality with True

Answer (score 0):

The value of the variable `current` is the condition. If it's truthy, the loop continues, if it's falsy the loop stops. The expectation is that in the last element in the linked list, `next` will contain a falsy value. I assume that value is `None`, and in that case the loop is equivalent to:

```
while Current is not None:
```

If, instead, the linked list uses `false` as the end marker, it's equivalent to:

```
while Current != false:
```

Comment: There are other falsy values in Python than None so this is incorrect.

Comment: I said "I assume that value is None" because that's the typical way to implement something like this.